# How can i access this DOM element after async in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

When running this code, `progresstitle` gets undefined. I suppose its because the DOM is not ready after the async call. How can i fix that? I want to be able to access `progresstitle` once async is done. How?

CODE:

```
<script>

    export default {

      data() {
        return {
          content: {},
        }
      },

      created() {
        this.getProjects();
      },

      mounted() {      
        this.data = {
          dom: {
           progresstitles: document.querySelectorAll('[data-title="progress"]')
         }
       }

       this.init()
     },

      methods: {
        init() {        
        this.titles();
      },

      async getProjects() {
        const content = await this.$prismic.client.getSingle('identifier');
        this.content = content.data;
      },

      titles() {
        this.data.dom.progresstitles.forEach((item, index) => {
        const progresstitle = this.data.dom.progresstitles[index]; //progresstitle gets undefined
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```
<template>
  <div data-title="progress"></div>
  <div data-title="progress"></div>
  <div data-title="progress"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: what version of Vue?  you've tagged both v2 and v3... It makes sense to only tag the one you're using

Comment: Sorry, is version 3. Just want to reach more people. And since im using the "options style" its basically the same as version 2. Very similar atleast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use vue **ref** on the div elements? Here it's the documentation for it - https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html

Also this is an example that uses ref. If you open the console you can see each div element.
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-khorana-fri2en?file=/src/App.vue